# Pandas – selecting column based on cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of currency values in GBP by date:

```
                 USD       EUR       JPY       CAD       CNH
date                                                        
2017-06-29  0.770151  0.879765  0.006857  0.591919  0.113538
2017-06-28  0.773038  0.878451  0.006892  0.592764  0.113687
2017-06-27  0.781594  0.885069  0.006952  0.593128  0.114724
2017-06-26  0.785476  0.879456  0.007045  0.593763  0.114849
```

And another DataFrame containing values to convert in GBP:

```
           price        date currency
0    21404.00000  2017-06-26      USD
3    21445.00000  2017-06-26      USD
4        1.27213  2017-06-26      USD
5      111.67500  2017-06-26      JPY
6        1.27205  2017-06-26      EUR
8      111.65500  2017-06-26      JPY
9      111.65500  2017-06-26      JPY
```

My goal is to "join" the currencies DataFrame to the values, resulting in a new `rate` column:

```
           price        date currency      rate
0    21404.00000  2017-06-26      USD  0.785476
3    21445.00000  2017-06-26      USD  0.785476
4        1.27213  2017-06-27      USD  0.781594
5      111.67500  2017-06-27      JPY  0.006952
6        1.27205  2017-06-28      EUR  0.885069
8      111.65500  2017-06-28      JPY  0.006892
9      111.65500  2017-06-29      JPY  0.006857
```

I'm not interested in any method using `apply` or other kind of row-based iteration. Instead I'd be looking for a vectorised way of manipulating the first two DataFrames to obtain the third.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lookup` to find your rates and `assign` to drop in a new column

```
df.assign(rate=currencies.lookup(df.date, df.currency))

         price       date currency      rate
0  21404.00000 2017-06-26      USD  0.785476
3  21445.00000 2017-06-26      USD  0.785476
4      1.27213 2017-06-27      USD  0.781594
5    111.67500 2017-06-27      JPY  0.006952
6      1.27205 2017-06-28      EUR  0.878451
8    111.65500 2017-06-28      JPY  0.006892
9    111.65500 2017-06-29      JPY  0.006857
```